# Enable XML-RPC in PHP.ini

Tags: php, xml-rpc

I have Joomla and a component called MyBlog (azrul.com) installed.

To enable pinging of Technorati I must enable xml-rpc.

By default this is disabled on my Shared Hosting account and cannot be changed. However, DreamHost says you can create your own custom advanced php5 installation.

Instructions here: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Advanced_PHP_configuration

I followed those and now I can change my custom php.ini file.

On this line in that file:

> ;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll

I removed the ;

hoping to uncomment that line and turn on that functionality before updating the php.

Since I believe DreamHost is not Windows server, instead of .dll should it be .so?

Still no luck. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Christopher Beckwith

Comment: You have restarted the web server, right?

Comment: This question is not programming-related and should be posted on serverfault.com instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, it is a Centos server:

```
Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at azrul.com Port 80
```

- the extension as to be a .so
- you have to restart apache
- the extension has to be installed on the server
- the extension has to be not disabled (its functions and/or classes)

You can have a lot of info looking to [phpinfo()](http://php.net/phpinfo) output:

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this response. Actually, Azrul.com was just the website for the product myBlog I'm using, but yes DreamHost is not Microsoft, so sounds like your .so assertion is still valid.

On the DreamHost forums instructions on custom php5 install on shared servers, theres no mention of restarting apache. Isn't there only one apache for the whole server? So how would have it restarted only for my website? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Create a blank file with this content:

```
<?php var_dump(get_loaded_extensions()) ?>
```

You'll seee if your extension is loaded or not.
As already two times mentioned: You have to restart at least the Apache daemon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dl() if it's enabled for your account to use custom extensions without restarting web-server. See PHP manual.